# nodejs postgres JSON return in nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

looking for some help here.

I have a basic postgres select statement that simply returns a JSONb column.

******* Edit to add SQL query ************

```
anpool.query(`SELECT data as test
                        FROM appanalytics
                        WHERE to_date(data->>'dateTime', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                        BETWEEN $3 
                        AND $4
                        AND cid=$1 AND aid=$2`,[req.session.cID,req.session.AccountID,endDate,startDate]).then(analytics =>{

//This returns an array of objects, each object in the array 
// is wrapped in the column name as shown above
console.log(analytics)
});
```

Now this works fine however each object in the array is wrapped in the table name

```
[
  {
    test: {
      ip: '10.10.10.10',
      atID: 0,
      uuID: '084B98DE-6D89-490E-8238-E25DDC8E5C04',
      itemID: '0',
      timeEnd: '2021-07-28T13:40:16.788Z',
      actionID: 'speakerMainDetail',
      dateTime: '07/28/2021',
      location: [Object],
      timeStart: '2021-07-27T12:54:21.284Z',
      deviceType: 'web'
    }
  }
]
```

So, in this response you can see, the object is nested in 'test' I need it to be the top level, so each response object is not nested in test, any ideas on how that might be possible? Using nodeJS and pg npm.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your SQL and JS code, only then we can advise you what you need to change.

Comment: @Bergi I have added the actual query in question, thanks

Comment: Ah, yes, you get back an array of rows, each an object with the columns you were selecting. There's not really anything you can or should do against that - notice you cannot use `ip`, `atID` etc as column names since (presumably) these are dynamic. Just do `analytics.map(row => row.test)`.

Comment: Btw, if you're using node-postgres and not some wrapper around it, shouldn't you be getting a query result with a `.rows` property not an array?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it does come back wrapped in the .rows, then inside of that it returns JSONB data wrapped in the column name. However your comment to map the results worked perfectly! If you want to add an answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get back an array of rows, each an object with the columns you were selecting. There's not really anything you can or should do against that - notice you cannot use `ip`, `atID` etc as column names since (presumably) these are dynamic. You can do

```
anpool.query(
  `SELECT data as test
    FROM appanalytics
    WHERE to_date(data->>'dateTime', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    BETWEEN $3 
    AND $4
    AND cid=$1 AND aid=$2`,
  [req.session.cID,req.session.AccountID,endDate,startDate]
).then(result => {
   const analytics = result.rows.map(row => row.test);
   console.log(analytics);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it like this:

```js
const res = [
  {
    test: {
      ip: '10.10.10.10',
      atID: 0,
      uuID: '084B98DE-6D89-490E-8238-E25DDC8E5C04',
      itemID: '0',
      timeEnd: '2021-07-28T13:40:16.788Z',
      actionID: 'speakerMainDetail',
      dateTime: '07/28/2021',
      location: [Object],
      timeStart: '2021-07-27T12:54:21.284Z',
      deviceType: 'web'
    }
  }
];

const { test } = res[0];

console.log(test);
```